# How can CMake determine the version of Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmake

I need to check programmatically whether SP1 is installed for Visual Studio 2010, since all our prebuilt libraries were built with this version. What's the best way to do that in CMake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the value of the [`CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER_VERSION.html#variable:CMAKE_%3CLANG%3E_COMPILER_VERSION) global variable.

For VS10SP1, the version should be `16.00.40219.01`, for the non-SP1 version it should be `16.00.30319.01`.

If you are stuck with an old CMake version (older than 2.8.12) that does not support `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION`, take a look at the [`CMakeDetermineVSServicePack`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/module/CMakeDetermineVSServicePack.html) module.

Comment: I am stuck with an older version, indeed. Very concise answer, thank you.